# How to safe 2 inputs in 1 array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, input

I created 2 inputs. Now I want to safe the text from the inputs in ONE array. Then I want to let them show with a button.

I tried it so:

```
const storedUserInputs = [];
        function storeInput() {
          var input = document.getElementById("AutoSpeichern");  
          storedUserInputs.push(input.value); 
          input.value = ""; 
          console.log(storedUserInputs);
        }
```

But that just have 1 input, I need 2 + a button. Please help!

Comment: You've got the code there to add the value to the array for one of the elements, simply repeat that for the other input, changing the `id` to target that element. If you're using the same `id` for both `input`, then that's an issue and you'll need to change them. If you have issues implementing the above change, please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can see the context you're working in

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I made it so: let array = [];

  function speichern() {
    let eingabe1 = document.getElementById("eingabe1").value;
    let eingabe2 = document.getElementById("eingabe2").value;
    array.push(eingabe1, eingabe2);
    console.log(array);
  }
does that work?

Comment: Should do, but you tell me ;)

Comment: Yes! It actually does! Can I show that with a button?

Comment: Sure, add a click event listener to your button and call your function from there. Here's an example of how to add the event handler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#examples

Comment: U'r the best. THAAAAANKS!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, it can be done like this:

```js
const storedUserInputs = [];

function storeInputs() {
  const input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  const input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  storedUserInputs.push(input1, input2);
  document.getElementById('input1').value = '';
  document.getElementById('input2').value = '';
  displayInputs();
}

function displayInputs() {
  const displayDiv = document.getElementById('display');
  displayDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content
  storedUserInputs.forEach((input) => {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = input;
    displayDiv.appendChild(p);
  });
}
```